# Let $C(G) = \{a \in G \mid ax = xa, \forall x \in G \}$. Prove that $C(G)$ is a subgroup of $G$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $C(G) = \{a \in G \mid ax = xa, \forall x \in G\}$.

1. Prove that $C(G)$ is a subgroup of $G.$
2. Prove that if $y \in C(G)$ and $x \in G$ then $xyx^{-1} \in C(G)$.

I have the same example to solve 1 which is

[image]

but part 2 I don't know how solve it , I need help in part 2

Comment: If $y \in C(G)$ then $xy=yx$. Now what happens if you multiply $x^{-1}$ on the RHS of that equation?

Comment: will get the identity e=xx^-1

Comment: You have to multiply it on both sides

Comment: here is a link for MathJax: http://meta.matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/93/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 1):

If $y \in C(G)$, then $xy=yx$, for all $x \in G$. Multiply both sides by $x^{-1}$: $$xyx^{-1}=yxx^{-1}$$ and you will get $xyx^{-1}=ye=y$. Therefore,
$$xyx^{-1}=y\in C(G).$$

Comment: its the same as done by @graydad in his comments